# Spring Boot Reactive WebFlux application reuse inbout call's JWT to outbound calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have spring boot reactive application that validate inbound calls with JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver (multiple issuer) - this part working fine. But than I have to call other services via WebClient with already configured OAuth2 registrations (via application.properties) with different authentications to retrieve results. But outbound calls reuse inbound JWT token to this calls.

Outbound endpoints are imported to my project via openapi-generator-maven-plugin (with configuration: generator java, library webclient)

I had try to search for correct configuration for WebClient to initialize ApiClient but non of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to retrieve the `Bearer` string from the authentication in the security context and manually setting an `Authorization` header to `WebClient` requests (provided that the configured `Authentication` implementation stores the original token string, of course).

If you have configured a `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver`, you most probably have a `JwtAuthenticationToken` in the security context of authorized requests.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SampleController {
    private final WebClient otherResourceServer;

    @GetMapping("/something")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public Mono<Object> getSomething(JwtAuthenticationToken auth) throws URISyntaxException {
        return otherResourceServer
                .get()
                .uri("https://some.host/getSomethingElse")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(auth.getToken().getTokenValue()))
                .exchangeToMono(resp -> resp.bodyToMono(Object.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - finally after a lot of debugging I figure out that everything inside reactive Spring were working fine, my issue was that my temporary JWT token which I was testing my endpoint, was missing `"sub" : "principal_name"` entry which was the main issue for the rest of flow about validation and renewing JWT for third-party API calls. Now everything is working fine - for me a good lesson to read documentation better.